# Delete directory when the user was deleted in bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, userdel

How to create a bash script that will delete the content of the directory if the user was deleted? Suppose I have a `user1` and some file named `somedata`. I want to write script that will delete file `somedata`, when the `user1` is deleted.

I am trying to create bash file that will do that will loop in it. So far I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
if userdel $user1
then 
find . -name "somedata" -exec rm -rf 
fi
```

Comment: In order for this question to be properly scoped and answerable, you should indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. Alse, the scope of the problem is unclear. Any reasonably recent U*x system will take care of these things when you remove a user. Are you not using standard administration tools? Why not?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the `-r` option to `userdel`.
From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel):

> ```
> -r, --remove
> ```
>
> Files in the user's home directory will be removed along with the home directory itself and the user's mail spool. 
>   Files located in other file systems will have to be searched for and deleted manually.
>   The mail spool is defined by the `MAIL_DIR` variable in the `login.defs` file.

Mind that a user may well create files *outside* of their home directory which are harder to track after the user was deleted.

Comment: The user's previous files will still show as being owned by the same numerical user id; there just isn't a user *name* to associate with that id anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user has been removed, there is no "user" to find by that name.  But the [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) utility has an option **`-nouser`** to help:

> The primary shall evaluate as true if the file belongs to a user ID for which the [getpwuid()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwuid.html) function defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008 (or equivalent) returns NULL.

To use it, first just list the unowned files (to verify this is what you want to do):

```
find / -nouser
```

or (most implementations, yet not in POSIX):

```
find / -nouser -ls
```

and if the list does not find unexpected files, go ahead and remove them:

```
find / -nouser -exec rm -rf {}+
```

Answer (score 0):

[My version of `deluser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/deluser.8.html) comes with a `--remove-all-files` option.

That option will scan all filesystems for files owned by the user and delete them.